# Change the format of a XML string which have date timestamp in the middle inside a lot of text files in the same folder (*.txt)

Tags: text-processing, xml

I have a lot of text files with dates in XML formated as follows:

```
<DATA2020-04-13T08:59:05.427 />
```

Need to change into this:

```
<DATA>2020-04-13T08:59:05.427</DATA>
```

**Notes:**

The date and time vary between strings and they are not to be altered. Before and after this string in each line there is a lot more XML formated stuff.
Also using Unix `date` is not an option, I really need to change the XML string inside the files.

I was thinking to use `sed` / `awk` / `perl` find and replace maybe using wilcards. Can anyone please figure out a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please post what you've already tried yourself.

Comment: Is that the _actual_ data that you have? That does not look like XML at all to me. A bigger example would be good to see, something that shows the structure of the document.

Comment: it looks like broken xml, which is probably why they want to fix it.

Comment: @cas Well, it would be better to fix whatever created that XML instead of adding a post-processing step that may mess up other things.

Comment: yes, it would.   sometimes, though, it's faster and easier to just fix the broken output.  especially if it took hours or days to generate or was generated from data that's no longer available. sometimes you just have to deal with the broken crap you have rather than the perfect data you wish you had.

Comment: Can we assume that the opening `<DATA` and closing `\>` will ***always*** be on the same line and that there will ***never*** be a `>` before the closing `\>`?

Comment: If it's a one-off, then sure, repair the data using sed or awk. If this is a regular data feed that's arriving on a daily basis, then fix the source to generate real XML rather than constructing a system that immortalises the bug (and breaks on the day that the bug is fixed).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I specific wrote --- I really need to change the XML string inside the files --- That means I have no means of fixing what generated the XML like this. But problem was already solved by @cas answer.

Comment: "_I have no means of fixing what generated the XML like this"_ report the fault to your XML data supplier, and pester them to fix it. The fault prevents any form of XML parsing because _the data is not XML_.

Comment: Looks like a timezone issue. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo '<DATA2020-04-13T08:59:05.427 />' | sed -E 's/<DATA(20[^/]*) \/>/<DATA>\1<\/DATA>/'
<DATA>2020-04-13T08:59:05.427</DATA>
```

Or, using `=` as the delimiter instead of `/`, to avoid having to backslash-escape the `/`s:

```
$ echo '<DATA2020-04-13T08:59:05.427 />' | sed -E 's=<DATA(202[^/]*) />=<DATA>\1</DATA>='
<DATA>2020-04-13T08:59:05.427</DATA>
```

this makes it a little easier to read (of course, you'd now have to escape any `=` characters in the search pattern and replacement text).

---

You could use pretty much the same regexes in perl too (the main difference being that while `\1` works in perl to refer to capture groups, it's better and more correct to use `$1`), which has even more options for delimiting the `s` operator, e.g. matching pairs of `{` and `}`:

```
$ echo '<DATA2020-04-13T08:59:05.427 />' |
    perl -pe 's{<DATA(202[^/]*) />}                  
               {<DATA>$1</DATA>}'
<DATA>2020-04-13T08:59:05.427</DATA>
```

perl also has a `/x` modifer to ignore whitespace (including newlines) that isn't either escaped with `\` or in a bracket expression.  It ignores `#` comments too. The purpose is to make it easier to write more-readable, documented regexes in your code.

See `man perlre` for details on perl regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly! Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Using a sed that supports `-E` for EREs (e.g. GNU or BSD sed):

```
$ sed -E 's:<(DATA)([^ ]+) />:<\1>\2</\1>:' file
<DATA>2020-04-13T08:59:05.427</DATA>
```

otherwise using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ sed 's:<\(DATA\)\([^ ]*\) />:<\1>\2</\1>:' file
<DATA>2020-04-13T08:59:05.427</DATA>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -pe 's:g/ \<DATA ( <+[0..9]+[-T:.]>+ ) \s\/\> /{"<DATA>"~$0~"</DATA>"}/;'
```

OR

```perl
raku -pe 's:g[ "<DATA" ( <+[0..9]+[-T:.]>+ ) " />" ] = ["<DATA>"~$0~"</DATA>"];'
```

Sample Input:

```
<DATA2020-04-13T08:59:05.427 />
```

Sample Output:

```
<DATA>2020-04-13T08:59:05.427</DATA>
```

Above are answers coded in **Raku**, a member of the Perl family of programming languages. Both examples above have four general characteristics of note:

1. No guessing on backslashed characters:  if it isn't `<alnum>` (alphanumeric or underscore) it needs to be escaped,
2. Regex modifiers like `/g` for `global` now go at the head of the `s///` form immediately after the `s`, preceded by a colon. And either `s:global` or `s:g` works,
3. Perl's `/x` modifier is now the default in Raku (allows liberal whitespace between regex atoms), and
4. String concatenation in Raku is accomplished with `~` tilde.

Both examples above use an enumerated character class `<+[0..9]+[-T:.]>`, which very simply consists of the digits [`0..9`], plus the four characters [`-` `T` `:` `.`]. Also, while the first example above follows the traditional `s///` substitution idiom, the second example above uses Raku's new 'sans-backslash' replacement format (with an `=` equals sign in-between), which some readers may find to be more readable.

Finally, if you have any interest in DateTime  extraction/modification, Raku has you covered:

```
~$ echo '<DATA2020-04-13T08:59:05.427 />' | raku -pe 's:g[ "<DATA" ( <+[0..9]+[-T:.]>+ ) " />" ] = [DateTime($0~"Z")];'
2020-04-13T08:59:05.427000Z

~$ echo '<DATA2020-04-13T08:59:05.427 />' | raku -pe 's:g[ "<DATA" ( <+[0..9]+[-T:.]>+ ) " />" ] = [DateTime(now) - DateTime($0~"Z")];'
54862286.622457
```

https://docs.raku.org/language/regexes#Enumerated_character_classes_and_ranges
https://docs.raku.org/routine/DateTime
https://raku.org